# How is one-vs-rest implemented in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am trying to understand how scikit-learn handles the multi-class classification problem for support vector machines. I am focused at the moment on the 'one-vs-rest' case.

I have started with a simple example of 3 Gaussian blobs.

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# Create 3 different blobs
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=45, centers=3, random_state=3)

clf_3blob = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', decision_function_shape='ovr')
clf_3blob.fit(X, y)
```

My understanding is that the 'one-vs-rest' algorithm works by first reducing the blobs to 2 labels (e.g. label the blobs as 'blob 0'  and 'not blob 0' ) and then solving this binary classification problem in the standard way. This is then done for all blobs (i.e. this is repeated for 'blob 1' and 'blob 2').

So something like the following (ignoring 'blob 1' and 'blob 2' for the moment):

```
# Reduce 3 blobs to 2 blobs
y[y > 0] = 1

clf_2blob = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf_2blob.fit(X, y)
```

What is confusing me is that the decision functions appear very different - I expected them to be quite similar. To be specific:

```
clf_3blob.decision_function(X)[:,0]
```

and

```
clf_2blob.decision_function(X)
```

appear quite different. Does this mean that I have misunderstood how the one-vs-rest approach is implemented in scikit-learn?

Comment: Consider that Support Vector Machine Classifiers do implement a OvO strategy and `decision_function_shape='ovr'` is just used to provide a consistent interface with other classifiers (for the majority of which a OvR strategy is preferred). I would suggest to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992932/svm-ovo-vs-svm-ova-in-a-very-basic-example/64993259#64993259), too.

Comment: Thank you, excellent answer, that explains everything!