# svm.SVC() model with either 'ovo' or 'ovr' decision functions produces the exact same accuracy

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I want to create multiple classification models using scikit-learn's svm.SVC() function on the MNINST dataset for different parameter combinations. What I have found is that for the same parameters I get the exact same accuracies both on the training and on the test set when using either 'ovo' or 'ovr' decision functions.

The code I've written is below:

```
kernel='linear'
c = 0.001
decision = 'ovo'

clf = svm.SVC(kernel=kernel, C=c, gamma=gamma, decision_function_shape=decision, tol=1, random_state=random_state)
clf.fit(x_train[:1000], y_train[:1000])
print(f'Train Accuracy: {clf.score(x_train[:1000], y_train[:1000]) * 100:.2f}')
print(f'Test Accuracy for ovo: {clf.score(x_test[:1000], y_test[:1000]) * 100:.2f}')

decision = 'ovr'

clf = svm.SVC(kernel=kernel, C=c, gamma=gamma, decision_function_shape=decision, tol=1, random_state=random_state)
clf.fit(x_train[:1000], y_train[:1000])
print(f'Train Accuracy: {clf.score(x_train[:1000], y_train[:1000]) * 100:.2f}')
print(f'Test Accuracy for ovr: {clf.score(x_test[:1000], y_test[:1000]) * 100:.2f}')
```

The program prints:

```
Train Accuracy for ovo: 85.40
Test Accuracy for ovo: 73.40
Train Accuracy for ovr: 85.40
Test Accuracy for ovr: 73.40
```

I use 1000 samples just for this example, but the issue still persists when using the whole dataset.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Consider that `SVC()` by default makes use of an OvO strategy to deal multiclass classification. `decision_function_shape` parameter, somehow, is an artifice to provide a consistent interface with the majority of the classifiers, which implement an OvR strategy. You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992932/svm-ovo-vs-svm-ova-in-a-very-basic-example/64993259#64993259) eg for further details.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, SVC() can only implement OvO, but if decision_function_shape='ovr' it just transforms the OvO decisions into OvR?

Comment: Correct. Instead, to force an OvR strategy you should pass `SVC()` to an instance of `OneVsRestClassifier()`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!