# When to use OneVsRestClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, multiclass-classification

If the decision function of `svm.SVC` is by default `"ovr"`, why would we use `OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel="linear")` instead of just `svm.SVC(kernel="linear")`?

Comment: May https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992932/svm-ovo-vs-svm-ova-in-a-very-basic-example/64993259#64993259 help?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment @amiola. So in the end they are not the same from what I understood. svm.SVC uses ovo strategy then does a mapping of the decision function to its ovr version. Whereas OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC) does it directly. Am I right?

Comment: Do you know where can I find how computationally expensive OneVsRestClassifier can be? I am trying to decide which strategy is best for me.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. Not sure if I can help on the second point; however, if you're dealing with the linear case, make sure to also have a look at `LinearSVC()` (whose underlying implementation - based on the *liblinear* library - is heavily optimized and scales much better wrt the dataset dimension), though not being exactly consistent with `SVC()` (you'll find many posts on SO on the differences between the two).